# Cpp function overloading

Tags: c++, function, overloading

I am refreshing my knowledge using Sololearn App.
I have the following code that does not run.
Could someone please explain to me why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void add(int a, int b) {

    cout << a + b<< endl;   
}
void add(float a, float b) {

    cout << a + b;    
}

int main() {
    
    //calling
    add(5,6);
    add(1.2, 6.5);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Sololearn Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCfXN.png)

Comment: Always post complete error along with your question.

Comment: I doubt the quality of that app, using namespace is not recommended nor is using std::endl. Here are some more comments : https://onlinegdb.com/okN9dHkyP